# Laravel relationship across multiple tables fails

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following tabels

table check

```
 id
 name ...
```

table setting type

```
id
name
level //references id on table check
```

tabel settings

```
type, //references type on table setting type
name
value
```

So basically i would like to return all checks with settings

So i have in my models

1.Check model // references table check

```
    public function settingsval(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\AppSettingTypes','name','name.setting');
   }
```

On my AppSettingTypes // references table setting type

```
    public function settings(){
       return $this->hasMany('App\AppSetting','id','type');
   }
```

SO on my controller am simply doing

```
CheckModel::with('settingsval')
```

But everytime the settings array is empty even though there is data

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `level` column of table `setting type` holds the reference to check table then  your mapping would be something like

```
public function settingsval(){
   return $this->hasMany('App\AppSettingTypes','level','id');
}
```

hasMany definition

```
hasMany($related, $foreignKey, $localKey)
```

Its better if you could use a better naming convention for your related columns like `check_id` instead of `level` and so on

Comment: CheckModel::with('settingsval') now give me upto appsetting types but i would now like to get the settings not appsetting types

Comment: @GEOFFREYMWANGI If you want settings also then update your `with` part as `CheckModel::with('settingsval.settingsval')`

Answer (score 0):

If `level` column of table `setting type` holds the reference to check table then your mapping would be

```
public function settingsval(){
   return $this->belongsTo('YourCheckModelname','level');
}
```

And In table `check` model have the mapping like

```
public function settingtype(){
       return $this->hasMany(\App\AppSettingTypes::class);
    }
```

Like wise if `type` column of table `setting` holds the reference to setting type table then your mapping would be like

```
 public function settings(){
       return $this->belongsTo('YourSettingTypeModelname','type');
    }
```

and in `setting type` model have mapping like

```
public function settingsType(){
           return $this->hasMany('YourSettingModelName'::class);
        }
```

Then you have to do in your controller

```
CheckModel::with('settingsval') //get all settingvalues
```